# Check query result array's size

Tags: php, arrays

With the following code I can iterate through the elements of the returned array:

```
foreach ($GLOBALS['myDB']->getAssets($i['uId']) as $x)
```

But I can't figure out how to efficiently check the size of the returned array before entering the loop.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
$assets = $GLOBALS['myDB']->getAssets($i['uId']);
$size = count($assets);
```

Comment: Yeah I tried that before posting but it complained and after copying and pasting your line figured that i was missing a parenthesis :)

Answer (score 1):

You can use count to find out the length of an array

```
count($arrayName);
```